# how to get two table id in one click to save in third table in asp .net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i am create job portal in asp .net mvc 4(C#),i have problem in hoe to  apply job
i am create three tables Jobseeker,PostJobs & ApplyJobs.

**Jobseeker Table**

```
    public class JobSeeker
    {
        [Key]
        public long u_ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Headline name ")]
        [Display(Name = "Headline Profile")]
        public string head_profile { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Full Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string full_name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime dob { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Email ID ")]
        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Email address in the correct format")]
        public string email_ID { get; set; }
        //[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}",ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid Phone Number in the Format,XXX-XXX-XXXX")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile No")]
        public int mob_no { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Education")]
        [Display(Name = "Education")]
        public string edu { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Specialization")]
        [Display(Name = "Specialization:")]
        public string spec { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Institude ")]
        [Display(Name = "Institude")]
        public string institude { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Passing Year")]
        [Display(Name = "Year Passing")]
        public int year_pass { get; set; }

        //public byte[] upload_img { get; set; }
        public string Disability { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Job Location:")]
        public string job_loc { get; set; }

        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        public long a_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Area Areafk { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("UserProfile")]//use above or specify this

        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile UserPro { get; set; }
    }
```

**PostJobs Table**

```
public class PostJob
{
    [Key]
    public long po_ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long emp_ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name:")]
    public string comp_name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Job Location:")]
    public string job_loc { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address:")]
    public string adress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country:")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public string city { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State:")]
    public string state { get; set; }
     [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Desiganation:")]
    public string dsg { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Salary:")]
    public int salary { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Experiance:")]
    public string Experiance { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Job Description:")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Skills:")]
    public string skill { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Post Date:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime post_dt { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    //[Display(Name = "Functional Area:")]
    //public long a_ID { get; set; }


    //public virtual Area Areafk { get; set; }
    public virtual empprofile empprofilefk { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplyJob Table**

```
public class ApplyJob
{
    [Key]
    public int a_Id { get; set; }

    public int u_ID { get; set; }

    public long po_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Jobseeker jobseeker { get; set; }

    public virtual PostJob Postjobs { get; set; }
}
```

Click on apply button save u_ID & po_ID current  UserId  in ApplyJob Table.

Comment: So, the question is how to insert rows to tables or what?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear.

> > If you are worrying about the Id of Jobseeker and PostJob table that is autogenerated.

```
Jobseeker js = new Jobseeker();
....
//assign your property to js instance
....
PostJob pj = new PostJob();
....
//assign your property to pj instance
....
Context.PostJobs.Add(pj);
Context.Jobseekers.Add(js);
Context.SaveChanges();
ApplyJob aj = new ApplyJob();
aj.u_ID = js.Id; // after instance is saved to db EF will populate Id in instance
aj.po_ID = pj.Id; // after instance is saved to db EF will populate Id in instance
Context.ApplyJobs.Add(aj);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

or do something like

```
Jobseeker js = new Jobseeker();
....
//assign your property to js instance
....
PostJob pj = new PostJob();
....
//assign your property to pj instance
....
ApplyJob aj = new ApplyJob();
aj.jobseeker = js; // assign it to navigation property and ef will handle ids
aj.Postjobs = pj; // assign it to navigation property and ef will handle ids
//Add to dbsets here
Context.SaveChanges();
```

**Suggestion**

You don't need that third table as it looks like many to many relationship. So if you don't want to handle the insertion inside the third table you can avoid that by declaring `ICollection<Jobseeker>` in `JobPost` and ICollection in `Jobseeker` class it would force if to create third table for you which will be maintained and manipulated by EF.

Here is few link for your reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx